# Параллельное программирование C++ и OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

Начал изучать параллельное программирование. Для начала пытаюсь научиться как разными способами задавать количество потоков.
Два из трех возможных способов у меня получились, а именно:

1. Опция num_threads() директивы pragma omp parallel
2. Функция set_num_threads()

3ий способ с помощью переменной окружения OMP_NUM_THREADS, как его использовать?
Так же вопрос, почему pragma omp parallel игнорируется при компиляции через терминал?

Вот **C++ код:**

```
    #include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    
    
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
        {
            
            

            cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
           
        }
        return 0;

}
```

Компилировал через терминал командой - g++ -o Filename Filename.cpp --> Filename.exe

Однако вместо ожидаемых двух Hello World, выводится один.

Comment: openmp необходимо специально включать в команде компилятору. Как и кучу других вещей. Реалистичная команда компилятору занимает несколько строк.

Comment: Да никаких несколько строк. Просто добавьте ещё  `-fopenmp` и готово

Comment: @KoVadim а как использовать OMP_NUM_THREADS?

Comment: Задайте в переменных окружения или прям с консоли при запуске OMP_NUM_THREADS=3 a.exe. возле равно пробелов нет!

Comment: @KoVadim попробовал данный метод - не работает к сожалению

Comment: я только что под линуксом протестил. Все работает как нужно. покажите наблюдаемое поведение

Comment: @KoVadim к сожалению я работаю на windows

Comment: опишите наблюдаемое поведение

Comment: проверил только что под windows+clang. Работает как часы. Что бы передать с консоли делал так. вначале ввел команду `set OMP_NUM_THREAD=3`, а потом запустил скомпилированный бинарник. и в cpp удалил `num_threads(2)`